# Model value won't change in admin area in Django

Tags: python, django

At the moment I'm going through **[Writing your first Django app, part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/)** of Django themselves.

Everything has gone fine, only one problem though. When creating the models I can't update the value of the Question text inside the admin area when edit and saving. It just shows the default value (What's new?) that I setup from the shell with the following:

```
q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Choice, Question

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
    (None,                  {'fields': ['question_text']}),
    ('Date information',    {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Is there something I didn't do correctly?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *I can't change the value of the Question text*

Comment: @mic4ael: Sorry about that, I can edit and save. But the value won't change.

Comment: It is hard to say what is the exact problem, but maybe you have a pending transaction?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right object. q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now()) will not result in a an entry getting into the db. you have to do q.save() on it. If you have done, I appologise for making this stupid comment.

Comment: @e4c5, I thought about the same, but he said that he is trying to edit the question in the admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. I missed adding a `__str__()` method to both Question and Choice.

So it didn't return the **choice_text** or **question_text**.

The models will look like this now:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```